# Make : make[2]: *** No rule to make target '<path/to/.so>', needed by '<target>'. Stop

Tags: cmake, makefile, ld, gnu

I am trying to include third-party libraries to my project  and build with CMake.

The source to be built is `main.cpp`present under `/src`.

My project directory is as follows -

```
   |-src
   |---main.cpp
   |-third-party
   |---ccalib_mdf
   |-----include
   |-----lib
   |-------libccalib_mdf-2-2-1.so
   |---dbcppp
   |-----include
   |-------dbcppp
   |-------libxmlmm
   |---------include
   |-----lib
   |-------libdbcppp.so
   |-------libxmlmm.so
   |-CMakeList.txt
```

I add my executable -

```
add_executable(mdf4_transcoder ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
```

I include the directories -

```
include_directories(mdf4_transcoder PRIVATE "third-party/ccalib_mdf/include")
include_directories(mdf4_transcoder PRIVATE "third-party/dbcppp/include/dbcppp")
include_directories(mdf4_transcoder PRIVATE "third-party/dbcppp/include/libxmlmm/include")
```

And try to link the directories and libraries-

```
target_link_directories(mdf4_transcoder PRIVATE "third-party/ccalib_mdf/lib")
target_link_directories(mdf4_transcoder PRIVATE "third-party/dbcppp/lib")

target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder Pcap++ Packet++ Common++ pcap pthread)
target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/ccalib_mdf/lib/libccalib_mdf_x64_2-2-1.so )
target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/dbcppp/lib/libdbcppp.so )
target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/dbcppp/lib/libxmlmm.so)
```

And I run the build process. However, this error is produced -

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/src/repair_service/transcoder/third-party/ccalib_mdf/lib/libccalib_mdf_x64_2-2-1.so', needed by 'mdf4_transcoder'.  Stop.
```

As it is a library built outside the project, I am unable to find the reason behind this error to occur. I searched for solutions, but found none where this error for a shared library is discussed.

***Note: This build process runs on cloud. I have no direct access to the environment.***

Comment: In verbose build mode, you usually get enough info to find the problem. Trigger it with e.g.  `cmake --build --verbose $MYBUILDDIR` or `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: The simplest way is to specify in `target_link_libraries` call the **absolute path** to the library you want to link.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried building the application on local linux env. I changed the `target_link_libraries()` to
```target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder Pcap++ Packet++ Common++ pcap pthread)  
target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/ccalib_mdf/lib/libccalib_mdf_x64_2-2-1.so )
target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/dbcppp/lib/libdbcppp.so )  
target_link_libraries(mdf4_transcoder ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/dbcppp/lib/libxmlmm.so)``` and it worked. However, while building it on AWS, using Docker image, encountered a No rule to make

Comment: I get the following error - `mmake[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/src/repair_service/transcoder/third-party/ccalib_mdf/lib/libccalib_mdf_x64_2-2-1.so', needed by 'mdf4_transcoder'.  Stop.`. At this point, i can't think of a reason for why this error occurs?

Comment: "No rule to make target" means that the referenced file doesn't exist. You could check that by executing (on docker) `ls /usr/src/src/repair_service/transcoder/third-party/ccalib_mdf/lib/libccalib_mdf_x64_2-2-1.so`.